# API/REST API Performance Testing within a Gateway Staging Environment. At what point which performance test procedure should be used correctly?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, development-process, rest-api, test-planning

In my current project, there is planning regarding a load and performance test within a staging environment and Jenkins pipeline based.

The question I'm only asking myself when and where to start in the individual stages, if we look at the possible test procedures of the performance and load test (based on SoapUI), I have various choices here which would inevitably be used in the ACC and STG environment, some of the procedures of course in production.

API Performance Testing

- Baseline Testing - Goal: Find metrics for system performance under normal load.
- Load Testing - Goal: Find metrics for system performance under high load.
- Stress Testing - Goal: Find the system breaking point.
- Soak Testing - Goal: Make sure no unwanted behavior emerges over a long period of time.
- Scalability Testing - Goal: Find metrics and check if the system performance changes appropriately to the load.

Which load and performance test can I use in the DEV staging environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the main purpose behind your test?

Try to define your SLO/SLIs first (KPIs). Usually SLO/SLIs are defined mainly by Product People. Of course Engineers could contribute , too.  You could read more how [Google defines it's SLI/SLO/SLAs](https://landing.google.com/sre/sre-book/chapters/service-level-objectives/).

When they are defined, you could think against which environement you want to run the perormance test. Usually, Dev environments are not identical to Live (at least when it comes to machine's powers).  I recommend to setup an environment similar to the Live and run your tests against that.

Last but not the least, Load Tests are usually expensive and is not happening very often, so don't do overengineering.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. We are considering load and performance tests within a build pipeline, which are controlled via an API gateway. So a direct tool integration into an existing process. Probably implemented by SoapUI or Jmeter.

Answer (score 1):

If your `DEV` environment has lesser hardware specifications than `ACC` and/or `STG` you can only do the following test types there:

- [Regression Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing) - to check that recent bugfixes or new features didn't cause performance degradations
- [Soak Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - to ensure that there are no [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) as the chance to detect them on scaled down environment will be higher
- [Integration Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) - complex system acts at speed of its slowest component, you should be able to detect any interoperability issues and the slowest parts even in DEV environment

More information: [Performance Testing in a Scaled Down Environment. Part Two: 5 Things You Can Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test/)